# Unite file_rec search misses a file

Tags: plugin-unite.vim, cygwin

I just started using Unite and I noticed that searching with *file_rec* doesn't return my vimrc. I've tried reinstalling Unite, clearing its cache with  and a few other things but nothing makes this file show up. Searching with the *file* option does return my vimrc though.

To be complete, my vimrc is symlinked from another folder (called .dotfiles). If I cd into .dotfiles, open Vim, activate Unite, and search with the *file_rec* option my vimrc will not show up.

I'm running Windows 8.1 in Cygwin if it might matter. Thanks for any help.

The problem still occurs with a minimal vimrc

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim'
call plug#end()

call unite#filters#matcher_default#use(['matcher_fuzzy'])
call unite#custom#default_action('file', 'tabopen')
call unite#custom#default_action('buffer', 'tabopen')
call unite#custom#default_action('tab', 'tabopen')
call unite#custom#default_action('jump_list', 'tabopen')

nnoremap <C-P> :Unite -start-insert file_rec<CR>
nnoremap <C-B> :Unite -start-insert buffer<CR>
```

Comment: It's common to disable the following of symbolic links when searching for files recursively to avoid infinite loops. Imagine `ln -s . self`

Comment: I have several other dotfiles that are symlinked in a similar manner in the same location and all of those show up. The symlinks are in ~ and the actual files are in ~/.dotfiles. I use Unite from ~/.dotfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this turned out to be a permission error with Cygwin. Deleting and recloning my dotfiles from github seems to have fixed the problem.